# Disable copy/paste in unlocked cells on protected sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to disable copy/paste in unlocked cells on protected sheet?

My specific problem is that while users should be able to edit unlocked cells, they should not copy data validation from one cell to another. Unfortunately data validation gets copied in a normal copy/paste operation.

So is it possible to disable copy/paste in unlocked cells on protected sheet or change the behavior of data validation so that it is not affected by copy/paste?

The suggested solution can be either Excel or VBA.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

put this code inside sheet

[image]